# Grep dot versus semicolon

Tags: r

Can someone explain why semicolon works and dot does not?
How can I fix this?

```
myv<-c("A", "B", "C", "D.E", "F", "G.H")
myv2<-c("A", "B", "C", "D;E", "F", "G;H")
multID<-grep(".", myv, value=TRUE)
multID2<-grep(";", myv2, value=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` is a metacharacter implying any character.  We need to either use `fixed = TRUE` or escape (`\\.`) or place it in square brackets (`[.]`)

```
grep(".", myv, value=TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Both escape and square brackets inside the double quotation `"\\."` and `"[.]"`?

Comment: @Al14  I meant either of these